# Slider / carousel issue on page loads

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, pageload

[image]

As you can see, this problem occurs when page is loading and user has a little bit slower internet or he/she visits the page for first time and content hasn't been cached.

Issue is that slides / carousel items are below each other when page is loading, then at some point goes *poof*, to normal.

**What could be done to fix this issue?**

- Should I hide slides / carousel items and then use jQuery to show them when everything has loaded?
- Initialize their code among first things on page load? Im afraid this will affect overall user feeling of loading speed and hault more important loadings.

I'm using Flexslider slider and Owl carousel, both have same issue and I'm suprised that they haven't thought about this problem.